# Springboot Database Initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

As I understand from `Spring Reference` docs, we can use the `data.sql` and `schema.sql` files for initializing the database.

When there are multiple instances of the application running against a single database, how to make the `data.sql` and `schema.sql` files run only once and instead of executing in all the containers.

Comment: you should look into liquibase with Spring Boot: https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/directory/integration-docs/springboot/springboot/

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the default spring data initialization. You can do this through your properties file by

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
```

While Spring at [9. Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization) does **not** recommend using multiple data source initialization technologies, if you want script-based `DataSource` initialization to be able to build upon the schema creation performed by `Hibernate`, set

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization
```

To true, this will defer data source initialization until after any `EntityManagerFactory` beans have been created and initialized.

And for managing your database across multiple application instance you can use `Flyway` and `Liquibase`, sing the basic `schema.sql` and `data.sql` scripts alongside `Flyway` or `Liquibase` is **not** recommended and support will be removed in a future release.